# Avoiding const_cast when calling std::set<Type*>::find

Tags: c++, set, constants, const-cast

Is there any good way to obviate the `const_cast` below, while keeping const correctness?

Without `const_cast` the code below doesn't compile. `set::find` gets a const reference to the set's key type, so in our case it guarantees not to change the passed-in pointer value; however, nothing it guaranteed about not changing what the pointer points to.

```
class C {
public:
   std::set<int*> m_set;

   bool isPtrInSet(const int* ptr) const
   {
       return m_set.find(const_cast<int*>(ptr)) != m_set.end();
   }
};
```

Comment: You are returning an iterator in a function that returns a `bool`, this code does not currently compile. Did you mean to use `return m_set.find(const_cast<int*>(ptr)) != std::cend(m_set);`?

Comment: Whoops, fixed. Thanks

Comment: `std::find` could help. I wonder if they ever partly specialize it to run in logarithmic time on `std::set` bounds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes**.

In C++14, you can use your own comparator that declares `int const*` as *transparent*. This would enable the [template overload](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/find) of `find()` that can compare keys against arbitrary types. See this related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18939882/raw-pointer-lookup-for-sets-of-unique-ptrs/). And here's [Jonathan Wakely's explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20317413/what-are-transparent-comparators).

Answer (score 1):

I want to explain the underlying logic of why this is impossible.

Suppose `set<int*>::find(const int*)` would be legitimate. Then you could do the following:

```
set<int*> s;
const int* p_const;
// fill s and p
auto it = s.find(p_const);
int* p = *it;
```

Hey presto! You transformed `const int*` to `int*` without performing `const_cast`.

Comment: Following your logic comparing const and not const pointer should be illegal, or somebody can make this hocus pocus by `find_if()`. Pretty convoluted logic imho

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any good way to obviate the const_cast below, while keeping const correctness?

I am not sure whether what I am going to suggest qualifies as a "good way". However, you can avoid the `const_cast` if you don't mind iterating over the contents of the set yourself. Keep in mind that this transforms what could be an O(log(N)) operation to an O(N) operation.

```
bool isPtrInSet(const int* ptr) const
{
   for ( auto p : m_set )
   {
      if ( p == ptr )
      {
         return true;
      }
   }
   return false;
}
```

Comment: Is there somebody in good mind that would pay O(N) vs O(log(N)) just to avoid const_cast?

Comment: @Slava, I wouldn't but I can't speak for everybody.