# Problem converting from const ptr* to ptr*

Tags: c++

I'm trying to implement a simple bidirectional map data structure. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21760343/is-there-a-more-efficient-implementation-for-a-bidirectional-map) helpful link and I decided to implement it in the second way stated in the accepted answer. My code:

BiMap.h

```
template <typename X, typename Y>
class Comparator
{
public:
    bool operator() (const std::pair<X, Y*>& e1, const std::pair<X, Y*>& e2) const;
};

template <typename T1, typename T2>
class BiMap
{
public:
    void insert(const T1& a, const T2& b);
private:
    std::set<std::pair<T1, T2*>, Comparator<T1, T2*>> map1_;
    std::set<std::pair<T2, T1*>, Comparator<T2, T1*>> map2_;
};
```

BiMap.cpp

```
template <typename X, typename Y>
bool Comparator<X, Y>::operator() (const std::pair<X, Y*>& e1, const std::pair<X, Y*>& e2) const
{
    return e1.first < e2.first;
}

template <typename T1, typename T2>
void BiMap<T1, T2>::insert(const T1& t1, const T2& t2)
{
    auto itr1 = map1_.emplace(t1, nullptr).first;
    auto itr2 = map2_.emplace(t2, nullptr).first;
    itr1->second = &(itr2->first);      // ERROR
    itr2->second = &(itr1->first);      // ERROR
}
```

main.cpp

```
int main()
{
    BiMap<int, string> M;
    M.insert(1, "one");
}
```

On compilation, I'm getting the following error:

```
c:\users\lucieon\source\repos\algorithms\trie\trie\suffixtree.inl(17): error C2440: '=': cannot convert from 'const _Ty1 *' to 'const _Ty2'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty1=std::string
1>        ]
1>        and
1>        [
1>            _Ty2=std::string *
1>        ]
1>c:\users\lucieon\source\repos\algorithms\trie\trie\suffixtree.inl(17): note: Conversion loses qualifiers
1>c:\users\lucieon\source\repos\algorithms\trie\trie\suffixtree.inl(12): note: while compiling class template member function 'void trie::BiMap<int,std::string>::insert(const T1 &,const T2 &)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T1=int,
1>            T2=std::string
1>        ]
1>c:\users\lucieon\source\repos\algorithms\trie\trie\trie.cpp(140): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void trie::BiMap<int,std::string>::insert(const T1 &,const T2 &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T1=int,
1>            T2=std::string
1>        ]
1>c:\users\lucieon\source\repos\algorithms\trie\trie\trie.cpp(139): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'trie::BiMap<int,std::string>' being compiled
1>c:\users\lucieon\source\repos\algorithms\trie\trie\suffixtree.inl(18): error C2440: '=': cannot convert from 'const _Ty1 *' to 'const _Ty2'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty1=int
1>        ]
1>        and
1>        [
1>            _Ty2=int *
1>        ]
1>c:\users\lucieon\source\repos\algorithms\trie\trie\suffixtree.inl(18): note: Conversion loses qualifiers
```

I understand that `itr1->first` and `itr2->first` are part of the `const` key for `map1_` and `map2_` respectively and probably that's why I'm getting this error but this is the only way I can make this data structure work. Is there any simple work around for this?

Comment: What is this std::set<std::pair<T1, T2*>, Comparator<T1, T2*>> map1_;?

Comment: you cannot change `std::set`'s elements, maybe it's better to use `std::map` to store not pointers but iterators?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Basically the Comparator is comparison function which sorts only on T1 and let's say if I want to make a bidirectional map between int and string, the pair will be `std::pair<int, string*>`.

Comment: @lucieon You have not understood my question. What is the maening of the comma in this line between set and comparator?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow isn't that how you pass your custom comparator function to a set?

Comment: @lucieon Oh, I have understood.:)

Comment: @user3365922 I tried it using `map` but still get the same error `Conversion loses qualifiers` when trying to copy address of `t1` to the value at `map2_[t2]` and vice versa.

Comment: @user3365922 Interesting idea about the iterators though will they remain valid after an insertion?

Answer (score 0):

you cannot modify std::set elements after the fact as it simply could no longer ensure uniqueness then. It seems you want to have a std::map.
Now the question is what do you want as your key and what as your value. When you start using pointers the question arises who owns the objects and whether they will always remain at the exact address.

Starting point **might** be:

```
std::map<T1, const T2*, Comparator<T1, T2*>> map1_;
std::map<T2, const T1*, Comparator<T2, T1*>> map2_;
```

...

```
auto itr1 = map1_.emplace(t1, &t2).first;
auto itr2 = map2_.emplace(t2, &t1).first;
```