# How to properly write and read class instance with vtable into the QSharedMemory?

Tags: c++, qt, shared-memory, virtual-table

I have a class derived from an interface

```cpp
class Interface {
public:
  virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class Implementer : public Interface {
public:
  void foo() override { std::cout << "Hello world" << std::endl; }
private:
  int __some_int_member;
};
```

Now I want to write a program, which will get the same instance of `Implementer` class in all application instances. I followed the example suggested [here](https://evileg.com/en/post/147/) (the second one), but in that example, only a single byte is being used.

```cpp
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
  Implementer *impl = nullptr;
  QSystemSemaphore accessor("app_accessor", 1);
  accessor.acquire();
#ifndef QT_OS_WIN
  QSharedMemory mem_fix("my_class");
  if(mem_fix.attach())
  {
    mem_fix.detach();
  }
#endif
  QSharedMemory mem("my_class");
  if(!mem.attach())
  {
    mem.create(sizeof(Implementer));
    new(mem.data()) Implementer();
  }
  impl = (Implementer*)mem.data();
  accessor.release();

  impl->foo();
  return app.exec();
}
```

The first instance works fine. But it crashes for the second one on line `impl->foo()`.

I think the reason is a bad cast from `void*` to the `Implementer*`. But I don't know how to do that correctly.

Any suggestions?

## Edit

I realized, that the crash caused by the **Segmentation fault** was the result of inheritance because without the base class everything works just fine.

## Edit 2

After some debugging, memory dump and some comments, I realized, that the problem is that in runtime the first instance of the program creates the `vtable` in its stack and puts the `vptr` to its `vtable`. The second instance gets the same `vptr` which, unfortunately, points to some random memory (that might be allocated or not).

Comment: Don't use `void*`. There's always a better way.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I don't. The function `QSharedPointer::data()` returns the `void*` to the memory.

Comment: @arsdever I think your answer lies in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905237/where-in-memory-is-vtable-stored) question. The vtable is stored in local memory, and your second app instance tries to reach that space.

Comment: @seleciii44 If so, could you please suggest some solution to the problem?

Comment: @seleciii44 Finally I got your point. And I realized the whole problem. It's kinda bigger than I expected. But it didn't solve my problem. Now I am more confused.

Comment: @arsdever why dont you separate data to share from the logic? Define a new class with only data, share that and apply some functions on it. in your example your implementer does not have any data. whats the point of having it shared?

Comment: @seleciii44 In my project I work on there are some data I'm keeping in `Implementer` class. It is a simple `QMap<>`. I liked your advice and probably will implement my code in that way. For a clean Q&A please provide your solution into an answer that I could accept.

Comment: @arsdever it is midnight in turkey and i am just about to sleep :) i will write it in the morning tomorrow.

Comment: I would not do that thing above as means of interprocess communication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A base class with virtual functions requires a `vtable`. [The memory location of the vtable or even the existence of it is implementation-dependent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905237/where-in-memory-is-vtable-stored), thus you get an exception when you try to access a function via `vtable`.

What you can do is separate the data and logic. Define a new class with only data, share that and apply some functions on it.

However, it seems like you are going to have some more issues since you are planning to share `QMap` as data. It probably stores its data on the heap and does not provide a memory allocator interface (at least I couldn't see). Meaning that you won't be able to control where it allocates the data. If you are certain that you need a map structure, you can use `std::map` and provide your own memory allocator to the map which uses the shared memory you've created. I've just written `c++ std map custom memory allocator` in google and it shows some solutions. There is also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373796/custom-memory-allocator-for-stl-map) question in SO that may help you.