# Use Memory Pool with Custom Allocator for STL Containers

Tags: c++11, memory-management, stl, dynamic-memory-allocation

I would like to be able to pass to the STL containers (vector, unordered_map, etc) the memory pool from which they need to allocate. I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373796/custom-memory-allocator-for-stl-map)  but it does not address the specific problem I'm facing.
I already have a working custom allocator that I can specify in the container declaration but could not figure out a way to pass the address for the allocator to use internally (via the placement new operator), from the application. Basically, I would like to go

From:

```
std::vector<int, myCustomAllocator<int>> myVector;
```

to:

```
void* pool = getMemoryPoolAddress();
std::vector<int, myCustomAllocator<int>/*Specify memory pool somehow*/> myVector;
```

How can I pass `pool` to my allocator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard library allocator is stateless (see [CppCon 2015: Andrei Alexandrescu “std::allocator is to Allocation what std::vector is to Vexation”](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LIb3L4vKZ7U) for context). This means that your concrete allocator type can have only one state (monostate) - global one, or `static` in C++.

So the question you linked contains the answer to your question:

```
class MyPoolAlloc {
public:
  static MyPool *pMyPool;
  ...
};
```

```
MyPool* MyPoolAlloc<T>::pMyPool = NULL;
```

It's how you can specify your pool for your allocator type.